# Upgrade magento 1.8 to magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.8, upgrade, magento-1.9

i'm trying to upgrade my magento1.8 to magento1.9  in my local magento

how to upgrade it with all my local files and custom changes?

i have tried [**this**](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-and-ee113-upgrading) in local magento, but not working.

could someone explain it step by step.

Comment: Please provide information about a specific issue. What you're asking is too broad.